# Fastify prettyPrint log in local time?

Tags: node.js, fastify

I've figured out how to pretty-print the logs in `fastify`:

```
const server = fastify({
    logger: {
        prettyPrint: __DEV__ && {
            translateTime: 'h:MM:ss TT',
            colorize: true,
            ignore: 'pid,hostname'
        },
    },
})
```

But the time is in UTC. How can I get it in my local time or specify a timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pino-pretty@4` you need to set:

```
translateTime: 'SYS:h:MM:ss TT Z o',
```

All the [cli args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-pretty#usage) can be set with the option json